# Use VBA Input value in to web page with HTML/JAVA with no tags/ids

Tags: internet-explorer, vba, excel

I've been staring at the screen for the last two days trying to understand how to resolve this issue...to no avail.

I have created a simple VBA search tool that affectively finds a value. I wanted to create some further code to enter this value in to an internal database that is accessed via an URL.

I know how to fill out an html web form using vba excel however the database has an interface form that i like to do the same thing and i can't figure out for the life of me how do to do it beside sending keys to the active screen.

I believe the issue lies in the fact that there is no reference to the part of the HTML code that I believe to be JAVA, and this is the input i'd like to change the value of.

[SOURCE CODE OF SITE/DATABASE]

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE></TITLE></HEAD>
<FRAMESET id="Frame1" frameSpacing="4" border="1" cols="280,80%" frameBorder="0">
<FRAME src="/frames/topics.html" name="topics" />
<FRAMESET id="Frame2" rows="50%,50%">
<FRAMESET id="Frame3" rows="40,*">
<FRAME src="/frames/uppermenu.html" name="uppermenu" scrolling="no" NOSCROLL="" /><FRAME src="/frames/upper.html" name="upper" />
</FRAMESET>
<FRAMESET id="Frame4" rows="40,*">
<FRAME src="/frames/lowermenu.html" name="lowermenu" scrolling="no" NOSCROLL="" /><FRAME src="/bin/lower_frame?CLASS_NAME=DRAWING_2D" name="lower" />
</FRAMESET>
</FRAMESET>
</FRAMESET>
</HTML>
```

However this is just the main script, and the value I'm trying to change is embedded in the Frame 3 section, which seems to be JAVA. When stepping through some other code in VBA it would only see "upper" as a tag name. And a form search doesnt indicate any in VBA even though it has a form reference in the HTML code.

The specific code line is:

```
<input name="NAME" type="text" size="15" value=""/>
```

I am desparate to figure this out, bearing in mind i've only ever used VBA, this is definitely a jump up. If anyone can give me any direction on this i would really appreciated it.

Thanks

P.s. Sorry if I haven't used the quotes right for this site, its my first time on posting on any forum.

Comment: That's not Java, just a standard HTML document containing nested framesets. You may be able to get to the specific document you want using something like `objIE.document.getElementById("Frame3").frames(1).document`

Comment: Have you tried using [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to find the URL that is used to post information to the DB?  Once you have that, you can then set up a simple POST to insert the data you need to add.  Or you can try to get access to the DB itself, which would be preferable.

Comment: Try directly opening that frameset in a web browser - just put foo.bar.com/frames/uppermenu.html - obviously adjust for correct domain and root folder

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your responses. @Tim Williams - I originally tried this by using below: 


`Set resultClasses = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("FRAME")`
`For Each resultClass In resultClasses If resultClass.Name = "upper" Then`
`***    resultClass.getElementsByName("NAME") ***`
`Set allResultsDiv = resultClass` 
`Exit For` 
`End If` 
`Next resultClass`

Comment: Unfortunately I can only seem to access the frame upper, and not access any lower into the frame. It fails on the line with the 3 astrix either side. When the expressions and values in VBA the 'resultclasses' indicates 5 which is correct, and the third one is the 'upper' one, this is where I get stuck in going in to the next levels, even when i hunt through the expresions in VBA there is no name or id that I see I can really access.

Hi @Kevin Pope, I tried the fiddler approach, however there doesnt seem to be any feedback/response from the database that can be utilised.

Comment: Hi @barrowc, I seem to get a webpage that says 'PDM Anydocs Client (Required for loading office documents)', even when I download this I'm still provided with the same message.

Any ideas guys?

Thanks

Comment: @Lee Mason - did you try what I suggested?

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams I did but unfortunately did not seem to help, and nothing really occurred when stepping through the code.

Comment: Make sure you allow enough time for the whole page (including all of the frame content pages) to load.  If you just wait for the frameset to load, then the other pages might still be incomplete.